# Proper way to include JHTMLString class?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

What is the proper way to include the class JHTMLString in Joomla 2.5?

```
jimport('joomla.html.html.string');
```

and

```
jimport('joomla.html.string');
```

doesn't work.
The only way I've managed to include this class is through:

```
JLoader::register('JHTMLString'), pathtotheclass);
```

Could this be a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Where are you trying to load it? e.g. component, module, or a plugin - if a plugin what type?

Comment: No matter where I try, it simply doesn't work. Tried from Component entry file, plugin file, module file and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your loading it in the only, *atleast atm* correct way:

http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtmlString

Because the normal way :

http://docs.joomla.org/JHtmlString/1.6

Doesn't seem to work, and I've tested it.

Comment: Strange. Why should this class not be imported like all other classes in the Joomla library?

Comment: Don't have a clue, I had a look around in the code and couldn't find something strange. Would you be so kind as to report it to the Joomla bug tracker ?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but I had the same problem on Joomla 2.5 so I had to call it like

```
JHtml::_('string.truncate', $text, 200);
```